# Jquery: Trigger on page load doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, events, triggers, click

I'm trying to trigger a click event on page load but it doesn't seem to be working..

I can't see any errors in the Firebug console...

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
      alert("Loaded.");
      $('.a-category .active').trigger('click'); 
    });
});
```

I added the alert just to check if it's working. And it does alert..

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: take out the `$(window).load(function(){` part. don't think it will solve your problem, but it's not needed unless you really want to wait for all elements on the page to load (images and whatnot)

Comment: show the html. You probably dont need the space between `.a-category .active`

Comment: did u try using just `$(el").click()`?

Comment: @sgroves I did take it out but it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: @karthikr <div class="a-category active">Websites</div>

Comment: by looking at your html, @karikr's answer is surely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
$('.a-category.active').trigger('click');
```

Since the html is

```
<div class="a-category active">Websites</div>
```

The listener should be for both the classes present on the same `div`

Currently, you are looking for class `active` in the children/grandchildren nodes of node with class `a-category`, hence the 'click' is not getting triggered.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's still not working. Would it be ok if I put the whole hierarchy so for example $('#mainDiv.categories.a-category.active')...?

Comment: It does not matter - It should have worked. Did you remove `$(window).load(function(){` like @sgroves recommended

Answer (score 0):

This code is correct

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Loaded.");
    $('.a-category .active').trigger('click'); 
});
```

if that doesn't work, your selector (the `'.a-categry .active'`) might be incorrect. are you trying to select an element with both classes, or one inside the other?

you can also just call `$('.a-category').click();` on an element, which will trigger the click on it

Comment: "this code is correct" then you go on to say why it might not be. it should be very easy for you to test which one works and update your answer with the correct solution

Comment: no, you misunderstood. The code that I posted is correct jQuery and will work in any situation as long as the element the selector is looking actually exists on the page. Then i stated that the selector he's using may not be correct in his specific situation, which i suspect might be the problem

Comment: ah, I didn't see that. either way, my answer was correct and didn't deserve a downvote. if I had seen his posted html, I would not have just suggested to change the selector, but would have told OP to use $('.a-category.active').click();

Comment: i didn't downvote you (but it looks like who did removed it, so no worries)